# When image transforming png to jpg, alpha layer become lined

Tags: image-transforms

I have several png images that when transformed from png to jpg, the alpha layer is transformed to an horizontally lined pattern.

Therefore I have to keep them as png, wich is in my case unnecessary and a drastic data load issue.

The problem appears in production, wich is an ArcusTech server.

Anyone knows what it could be ?

Thanks !

Comment: Are you using GD or Imagick on the server? Also, alpha is transparency which is not supported by jpg. What exactly are you expecting here?

Comment: Ooooh I've looked into the installed dependencies on my prod, and only GD is installed. As Craft stands: "GD or ImageMagick is required, however ImageMagick is recommended as it adds animated GIF support, and preserves 8-bit and 24-bit PNGs during image transforms.".
I asked the ArcusTech team to install it since it could be the issue :-) 

Usually, alpha layers in png are replaced by plain colors in jpg (and generally plain white) as it does on my local.

Thanks already !

Comment: As Brad pointed out below, let's see how Imagick handles this. Should be much better.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to have [Imagick](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) installed on your box if you want to preserve alpha channels in a PNG during transforms.

If Craft sees it is installed, it will use it by default.

Comment: Thanks for your input ! Imagick is now installed and, surprisingly, the transform alpha layers of my jpgs-transformed-from-pngs are now black and not white as it is on my local

Comment: Are you running a newish version? https://www.imagemagick.org/script/changelog.php and https://pecl.php.net/package-changelog.php?package=imagick

Comment: Nope :-/ 
imagick module version 3.4.0RC6
imagick classes Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator, ImagickKernel
Imagick compiled with ImageMagick version ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64

Comment: Maybe try updating those and see if it helps.